# How to set MediaType for HttpResponse in Akka Http?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm building an endpoint which returns images with help of Akka HTTP. I get the images from AWS S3 as a Stream of `ByteString`'s. Every image has its own `MediaType` (`image/gif`, `image/png`, ...)

How to construct an HttpResponse entity with a particular media type when we have a media type string representation?

```
HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, entity = HttpEntity(image))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a `MediaType` from a string, use [`MediaType.parse`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.1.3/akka/http/scaladsl/model/MediaType$.html#parse(value:String):Either%5BList%5Bakka.http.scaladsl.model.ErrorInfo%5D,akka.http.scaladsl.model.MediaType%5D):

> ```
> def parse(value: String): Either[List[ErrorInfo], MediaType]
> ```
>
> Tries to parse a **MediaType** value from the given String. Returns **Right(mediaType)** if successful and **Left(errors)** otherwise.

For example:

```
MediaType.parse("image/gif") // Right(MediaTypes.`image/gif`)
```

[`HttpEntity`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.1.3/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpEntity$.html) can take a `ContentType`. To get a `ContentType` from the above `MediaType`, you could do something like this:

```
val mediaTypeStr: String = ???

val mediaType: MediaType =
  MediaType.parse(mediaTypeStr).toOption.getOrElse(/*a fallback/default MediaType*/)

val entity = HttpEntity(ContentType(mediaType), ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get media type by extension.

import akka.http.scaladsl.model._

val mediaType: MediaType = MediaTypes.forExtension("png")

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
val httpResponse = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`image/gif`, <byte array of your image>)
```

Comment: This is correct only in case if all images have the same `MediaType`. But I have at least 3 `MediaType`s. So the question is how to create `MediaType` from `String` value dynamically?